On the collection of objects on which a natural transformation between two $R$-linear functors on the derived category is an isomorphism
Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian  ring and $D(R)$ be the derived category of all $R$-modules. Let $F,G: D(R)\to D(R)$ be $R$-linear functors and $\eta:F \to G$ be a natural transformation. Assume that the collection $$\{X\in D(R)\mid \eta_X: F(X)\to G(X) \text{ is an isomorphism} \}$$ contains $R$ and is closed under arbitrary co-products. Then, is it true that $\eta_Y:F(Y)\to G(Y)$ is an isomorphism for every $Y\in D(R)$ ?
Note: Here, when I say $R$-linear functors, I do mean that $F,G$ commutes with shifts as well.

Yes, and it doesn't need "commutative Noetherian".
The category of objects $X$ for which $\eta_X$ is an isomorphism is a localizing subcategory of $D(R)$ (i.e., a triangulated subcategory closed under arbitrary co-products). We are told that it is closed under shifts, and then the fact that it is triangulated follows from a five lemma argument.
So the fact that it is the whole of $D(R)$ follows from the fact that the localizing subcategory of $D(R)$ generated by $R$ is the whole of $D(R)$. There are slicker proofs of this using more technology, but a relatively concrete proof can be found in my paper
Rickard, Jeremy, Unbounded derived categories and the finitistic dimension conjecture, Adv. Math. 354, Article ID 106735, 21 p. (2019). ZBL1470.16020,
where this is Proposition 2.2 (strictly speaking, that proves that the projective modules generate, but the comment just after the proof explains why that implies that the single object $R$ generates).
